# WP7: Multiple Puspins and Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

```
public void setMap()
    {
        GeoCoordinate mapCener = new GeoCoordinate(39.920794, 32.853902);
        Pushpin pin1 = new Pushpin();
        pin1.Location = mapCener;
        pin1.Content = hereContent;
        map1.Children.Add(pin1);

        foreach (var item in pinList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Location.Latitude.ToString()+","+item.Location.Longitude.ToString());
            mapCener = new GeoCoordinate(item.Location.Latitude, item.Location.Longitude);
            pin1 = new Pushpin();
            pin1.Content = "K";
            map1.Children.Add(pin1);
            map1.SetView(mapCener, 0);
        }

        int zoom = 10;
        map1.SetView(mapCener, zoom);
        map1.ZoomBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

I have a list of PushPins which contains coordinates of different locations. I also have center point, which shows the location of the phone.

I tried to add the pushpins to the maps the content "K" is shown on the left upper corner of the screen. My PushPin list contains correct coordinates but their position on the map is wrong. What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi there, i don't see the location of the pins in the foreach loop maybe this might cause the problem.

Comment: pinList contains the location of the pins. The MessageBox in foreach loop shows the locations as they are supposed to be.

Comment: I mean I haven't seen pin1.location in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do PushPin clustering, there is a good article here that has a good example of what you are trying to accomplish.

See http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/pushpin-clustering-with-the-windows-phone-7-bing-map-control/